# Magento 2 : shipping method in dropdown view in frontend

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, drop-downs

On Checking out,I have a lot of shipping methods listed.
Any solution, how to customize it into a drop-down?

[image: https://prnt.sc/pqmuly]

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try to create a custom module and override ***Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js*** component and its template

I assume you will create a custom module name **Company_ShippingDropdown**

After creating the custom module follow the steps below

**step 1)**

Create **requirejs-config.js** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/ShippingDropdown/view/frontend***

**File**: ***app/code/Company/ShippingDropdown/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js***

```
 var config = {
        "map": {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping": "Company_ShippingDropdown/js/view/shipping",
                "Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html":
                     "Company_ShippingDropdown/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html"
            }
     
        }
    };
```

step 2)

copy

***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js***

To

**YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/ShippingDropdown/view/frontend/web/js/view/**

Now update shipping.js as below

**File:** ***/app/code/Company/ShippingDropdown/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js***

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'    
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t,
    priceUtils
) {
    'use strict';

    var popUp = null;

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            ...
            ...
            shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Company_ShippingDropdown/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
            ...
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...    
        shippingSelectionChanged: function(newvalue){       
             var self = this;
            var shippingRatescollection =  self.rates();
            var selectedVal =  $("#myshipping-list").val();         
            if(selectedVal!=='' ){
                var arrcarierCode =  selectedVal.split("_");
                var selectedCarrierCode =  arrcarierCode[0]
                var selectedMethodCode =  arrcarierCode[1];
                $.each(shippingRatescollection,function( index, shippingMethod ) {
                         if(shippingMethod.carrier_code==selectedCarrierCode && shippingMethod.method_code==selectedMethodCode){                             
                             self.selectShippingMethod(shippingMethod);
                         }

                    });

            }

        },

        getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
            //todo add format data
            return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
        },  
        ...
        ...
        ...

    });
});
```

I have done few changes to the **shipping.js** file

1. inject one new js component (i.e
   '*Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils*')
2. change the shippingMethodListTemplate to
   '*Company_ShippingDropdown/shipping-address/shipping-method-list*'
3. Create one new function '***shippingSelectionChanged***'

**step 3)**

Now create the component template file **shipping-method-list.html** under ROOT/app/code/Company/ShippingDropdown/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address

**File :** ***app/code/Company/ShippingDropdown/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html***

```
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">    
     <select name="myshipping-list" id="myshipping-list" data-bind="options: rates() ,
                            optionsCaption: 'Please select a rate...',
                            optionsText: function(item) {
                                return element.getFormattedPrice(item.price_incl_tax)+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + item.method_title  + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'  + item.carrier_title
                                },
                            optionsValue:function(item) {  
                                                        
                               return item.carrier_code + '_' + item.method_code;
                            },    
                            ko-value: function(item) {  
                                                           
                               return item.carrier_code + '_' + item.method_code;
                            },
                            value:isSelected,    
                            event:{ change:shippingSelectionChanged }">
                    </select>     
</div>
```

**step 4)**

Now install the custom module and refresh Magento cache

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:flush

:: **Here is a working demo of shipping method dropdown** ::

[image]

Comment: awesome, Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: not working in 2.4.3-p1 version throwing console errors